# How to read QR-based vCard on Windows & Mac OS, with USB scanner?

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode, qr-code, vcard

I'm generating QR codes that contain vCards, and these can be consumed just fine by smartphones, e.g. with software like [RedLaser](http://redlaser.com), etc.

For the desktop I have a barcode scanner that can read QR (2D), but how can I read the vCard into a spreadsheet or some other way that I can use the data easily. If I do it now with Notepad, Word, etc it just outputs the raw vCard code as a single entry/string, which is not very helpful :/

Ideas?

Update:

What I currently get when I scan on Windows (e.g. Notepad) is the raw vCard string:

```
BEGIN:VCARD 
VERSION:2.1 
N:John;Doe
FN:John Doe
ORG:MyOrg 
TEL;WORK;VOICE:555-777-1111 
ADR;WORK:;;28 WST, CA 4, 23010, United States 
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:jd@gmail.com 
END:VCARD
```

Comment: What options does the scanner software offer with regard to how it handles the data it produces? For example, can you have it write the vCard data to a file with extension `.vcf`, and then tell it to invoke a given program on that file? (More generally, what scanner software are you using?)

Comment: None. I just plugin the scanner and eh OS detects it. Do I need specific software to make sense of vCards?

Comment: Not as such; lots of things (especially mail clients) understand `.vcf` files, but don't recognize raw vCard when it's not in a file with that extension. Exactly what happens when you scan a QR code?

Comment: If I scan with MS Excel in the foreground, I get the raw code in a single cell. If I scan with RedLaser, I get the contact in my address book.

Comment: Sounds like it's just dumping the scanned data into the clipboard, and pasting it into whatever application happens to have focus at the moment -- a rather lazy approach, I must say. Your best option might be to set up an address book specifically for RedLaser to add contact information to, and then export that in a format Excel can understand.